# Compare the previous row with the current one

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare the previous row's value with the current one and depending on the comparison record a comment.
This is my dataset excerpt:

```
+-----------------------------------+----
|              depth    |col1| fomration|
+-----------------------------------+----
| 2300                  | 1 |    form1  |
| 2305                  | 2 |    form2  |
| 2310                  | 2 |    form2  |
| 2315                  | 3 |    form2  |
| 2320                  | 3 |    form3  |
+-----------------------------------+----
```

What I need to do is to compare the value in the formation column and if it is not equal to the previous value, write new column where the comment will be equal not equal... What I have tried is the following code:

`data=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
 formation_update=[]`

```
for i in data.formation:
if row[i]==row[i-1]:
    formation_update.append('eqaul')
else:
   formation_update.append('not equal')

data['formation_update'] = formation_update
```

This is the output of the code:

```
    if row[i]==row[i-1]:
    TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptableenter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df['comparison'] = np.where((df['a'].shift(-1) == df['a']), 'equal', 'not equal') 
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
   a  b comparison
0  1  5  not equal
1  2  6      equal
2  2  7  not equal
3  4  8  not equal
```